# Difference between using parenthesis and sqaure brackets for creating dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Dynamic arrays are allocated in C++ like this.

```
int *arr = new int(5);
int *arr = new int[5];
```

What is the difference between these ways? Or Are they exactly same?

Comment: The second is a pointer to dynamic allocated int array of size 5. The first is a pointer to an int with 5 as its value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array is only created when you use `[]`.  If you are not using `[]`, then you are not creating an array.

`int *arr = new int(5);` allocates a single `int` and gives it the value of `5`.

`int *arr = new int[5];` allocates an array of 5 `int`'s with no specified value in each element.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks.